# mysql doesn't do anything, it just shows a "->" in a new line

Tags: debian, terminal, mysql

I don't know what's wrong with MySQL. I'm on Debian, and no matter what command I enter, like `CREATE DATABASE` or `USE` it just jumps to a newline, showing a `->`. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Did you remember to terminate your SQL commands with `;`?

Comment: show us what you did

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Well, I'm stupid! Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the posted answer has addressed your issue please do remember to accept it with the tick mark on its left side.

Answer (score 3):

SQL queries can an are often written on several lines as they can easily get lengthy. So the newline character in SQL is just another form of whitespace and queries have to be terminated by a semi-colon (`;`).

So until  you enter that `;`, the query is not terminated and if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `mysql` reminds you so by issuing a secondary prompt.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but I know I'm terminating the lines with a semicolon.